# Interpreting number on x-axis of semivariogram in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-statistics

Using ArcGIS 10.3.1

The attached image shows a semivariogram. The lag size is 65000 (meters), which makes sense based on my data and map units. My understanding of the x-axis is that it is the distance between the pair points. That is, points on the left are closer together, points on the right are farther apart. Why does my x-axis show such small numbers? 6.5 x 10 -5?  What are the units?

I realized by modifying it more that the end of the x-axis is the lag size * # of lags, or in this case, 65000*10, or 650,000. But again, the units should be 6.5 x 10^5, not 10^-5.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found some version of the answer. It does not make much sense to me, but I guess the units are considered in reverse. The same seems to be true of the y-axis too.

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/10326

So what they label at 10^-5 (x-axis) or 10^-3 for y-axis, I would consider 10^5 or 10^3.